# Intellisense, auto completion with RequireJS in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, requirejs

I know javascript intellisense support trough _referencs.js in vs2012.
At this moment, I am using RequireJS in my frontend, but I think I lost auto-completion supporting in javascript since I started using RequireJS.

I found require.intellisense.js from [here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-intellisense), but, unfortunatelly failed with it after several hours and tries.

Is there anyone succeeded in getting auto-completion with RequireJS(version 2.1.2) in vs2012?

Answer (score 0):

I got Intellisense to work inside RequireJS defined modules by following this Code Project article:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460836/Making-the-most-out-of-JavaScript-Intellisense-in

The download code is at this link:  https://github.com/chrisprice/PropertyFinder-HTML5/zipball/master
The solution that has the working Intellisense is the iPhone solution.

You'll want to download the code referenced in the article and try it out.  Between the download code and that article, you should be able to take it from there to implement Intellisense in your own project.

There is a require.intellisense.js file in the source code for the article that is critical to proper operation.  I'm not sure who wrote it, but it is different than the one you reference from jrburke.

If you have any follow up questions, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am able to get intellisence when I use full  file path like require(['./lib/knockout-2.2.0'], function(ko){}),  however if I use path option in requirejs to use alias, it always failed to get intellisence.

Comment: As you pointed, require.intellisence.js files are somewhat different, so I tried both of them, but failed to get intellisence.

Comment: when you use the path option to specify an alias, you have to also name the defined module accordingly.  So, say you have a path to specify an alias like so: module1: myCode/js/module1-1.0 your define call should be something like define("module1", function(require){ ...

Comment: In your example, you may to create your own define module to return KO, because the on provided by KO probably isn't named