# How do you get Visual Studio JavaScript reference directives to persist to local variables?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, requirejs, intellisense

I have "JavaScript IntelliSense" working in my visual studio project, but I am hitting a snag..

Lets say I have the following javascript file:

```js
/// <reference path="~/Content/scripts/_references.js" />

// I gots my intellisense working for jquery / backbone / underscore

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    // no intellisense for jquery / backbone / underscore
    return {};

});
```

When I am using requirejs, visual studio stops providing intellisesnse on $, _, and Backbone because of the local variables passed into the anonymous function.  Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14048851/34397

Comment: Gah, thought I had googled this one enough for a question.. Let me look into the link provided - thanks!